# Aggregate functions without min max time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset comprised of different world regions and I have a groupby argument that I would like to include not just the current output but also the associated dates of each of the min and max functions:

```
dfmin2 = df2.groupby('Region')['Student'].agg(['sum','min','max','mean']
```

produces:

```
Region   sum   min   max   mean
Canada   5     1     3    2.5
Mexico   10    2     6    5
```

I would like:

```
 Region   sum   min  min date   max  max date  mean
 Canada   5     1    year 6      3   year 2     2.5
 Mexico   10    2    year 8      6    year 9    5
```

Where the min date and max date are connected to when the min/max happened numerically for the min/max columns.  i.e., my dataset is 16 years long, i do not want the min and max to be years 1 and 16 for each case unless it just so happens that is the case (which is not possible)

Comment: Can you please provide your input dataframe.

Comment: You haven't given enough information.  I'd like to see the data.  Read [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly.  That said, you may want to use `'idxmax'` and `'idxmin'`  in this way: `df2.groupby('Region')['Student'].agg(['sum','min','max','mean', 'idxmax', 'idxmin']`  You could use the resulting data to get your answer but I can't tell without your input data.

Comment: Not data we can only guess , so my assumption `df2.groupby('Region')['Student'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax']).apply(lambda x : df2.loc[x,'year'].values)
`

Comment: Wen, thank you for your help, and I apologize for the lack of detail.  If I wanted to utilize your answer along with using 'mean, min, max' would i need to merge two group by's?  Or how would i incorporate these other aggregate functions?